# jQuery slideToggle callback function and toggleclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">CLICK</div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">CLICK</div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">CLICK</div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.c').hide();
$('.b').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.c').fadeToggle();

    if($('.b').eq(0).is(this)){
    $(this).toggleClass('yellow');
}
});
```

**[ONLINE SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nMskf/)**

How do I make once `slideToggle` finishes then start `toggleclass`, like the 1st box, I'd like it to change to yellow color once the fadeToggle finishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fadeToggle`'s callback function:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Kqc2B/

```
$('.b').click(function () {
    var that = this;
    $(this).next('.c').fadeToggle(function() {
        if ( $('.b').eq(0).is(that) ) {
            $(that).toggleClass('yellow');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Bruvo `:)` added the demo +1 good to see you after loong time

Comment: @Tats_innit Hey bro :), thanks, where are you man? long time no see.

Comment: are we able to do like this, the first click can be happened immediately (fast) and use callback function for 2nd click?

Comment: @olo Yes, you can use a flag(true/false), but I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @undefined, when click on the box, it changes red without callback function, and the 2nd click to change to yellow with callback function. which means, make it fast to change it to red, and change it to yellow after effect finishes. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the complete callback option provided by [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/), it will get called once the animation is completed

```
$('.c').hide();
$('.b').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next('.c').fadeToggle(function(){
        if($('.b').eq(0).is($this)){
            $this.toggleClass('yellow');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XXGvP/)